# Broadcast in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences, sensors

I am write Program that work with Proximity Sensors in android,all thing seems to be true,But When I am Running my app this is Worked for first time,means when checked box is false when user calling my app is detective service and don't use proximity sensor for answering call and when checked box is true this means my service active and when user calling,answering call used proximity sensor .
but all of this scenario **JUST** for one time accrued,other time in false or true state , my app answering call with proximity sensor 
Here is My code :

```
public class main extends PreferenceActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.setting);
    findPreference("AIR_CALL").setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            if (newValue.toString().equals("true")){
                Log.i("tag","start");
                Intent intent = new Intent(main.this,CallReceiver.class);
                startService(intent);
            }else{

            }
        return true;
        }
    });
}}
```

And My Broadcast Receiver:

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements SensorEventListener {
     private SensorManager mSensorManager;
     private Sensor mSensor;
     public static boolean isAirAnswerOn = G.preferences.getBoolean("AIR",false);
     String phoneState;
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("TAG", "Call Recieve");
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(android.hardware.Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        phoneState = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
}
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged (SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.values[0] == 0.0F) {

            if ((!isAirAnswerOn) | (!phoneState.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))) {
                Log.i("ACR", "Action Phone UP");
                Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON");
                localIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.KEY_EVENT", new KeyEvent(1, 79));
                G.context.sendOrderedBroadcast(localIntent, null);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = G.preferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("AIR", true);
                editor.commit();
            }
        } else {
            Log.i("TAG", "FALSE");

        }
    }
@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged (Sensor sensor,int accuracy){
}
```

}

thanks you :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to abort changing the value in your `OnPreferenceChangeListener` with `return false`. Otherwise the value is set to `true` and subsequent changes to `true` are ignored.